# Is there a ‘valid structure’ to pass query parameters via URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-parameters

Is there a wrong way to structure a URL when passing GET parameters via URL?

E.g., I want to redirect a user to a page that is a collection of news posts and I want to auto populate the form inputs that in turn filter the type of news post shown:

https://somesite.com/news?company=bobs-company&type=featured-news

Would it matter if the URL was structured exactly as follows:

https://somesite.com/news/?company=bobs-company&type=featured-news

Notice the trailing slash before the ?

I am using a CMS and the CMS automatically redirects any page to have a trailing slash.

Comment: The first would, most likely, try to serve a file called `/news`, whereas the second would serve the default file in directory `/news/`. It all depends on what you really have. I can't really tell from your question.

Comment: Hey KIKO thanks for the response. The first URL structure should definitely fill in form fields when that same url is accessed from a little page. More so, I am asking if the second url that has a trailing slash before the ? Would be considered wrong or not auto populate form fields simply because of the trailing slash before the ?

Comment: Both are valid URL's, but, as I tried to explain, one is pointing at a file, the other at the default file in a directory.

Comment: KIKO, that makes sense that it’s pointing at the default file in that directory if the path is /file/ but Wordpress doesn’t serve a directory it serves a file like /file and then if it does not have a trailing slash it will redirect any url that does not have a trailing slash, eg /file to /file/

Comment: So I have a page and on that page I want to link internally to my news page and I also want to pre-fill the form input to automatically filter by “news type” so I’m wondering if my automatic filtering/auto population of the form fields are not working correctly because of the trailing slash before the ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically most modern CMS systems will interpret /news & /news/ as the same page.

Personally I would use /news/ as most sites I work with include the trailing slash as default. Whichever you choose, just keep it consistent.